# system-wide password manager in iOS and OS X

Tags: ios, security, password

I'm booting up my AWS app in iOS and I'd like iOS to give me a stored password. Ideally I'd like it to be generated.  Is there any piece of software I can use to manage my passwords in the cloud and have access to them in any application in iOS, not just a browser?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I personally use (and obviously prefer) [1Password](https://1password.com). This is not cheap, but does regularly go on sale for much discounted prices.

1Password will do everything you want and more. It works across iOS, macOS, Android and Windows. You can watch a [video](https://vimeo.com/88901304) highlighting its features. And, you can also [try it out for free](https://1password.com/extlink/1password-signup/).

And of course, it offers extensions for Safari, FireFox, etc. You can also download it directly via the Mac and iOS App Stores.

**Disclaimer:** I have no affiliation with 1Password whatsoever.

Comment: Does it work system-wide, for apps like the AWS app and not just the browser?

Comment: Not exactly, because individual apps have to support it. Let me explain, using AWS as an example. First of all, I'm assuming by AWS you mean the Amazon Web Services app, correct? Well, due to user feedback, since version 1.14 of AWS it has supported 1Password. This means iOS users with the 1Password app installed can sign in using their vault password or Touch ID. They do this on the sign in page by tapping the 1Password icon on the top right corner and selecting the 1Password app. Now, does it work system wide with _all_ apps? No. But any app developer that wants to can support 1Password.

Comment: bitchin.  thx. !